# Jquery show multiple elements on Click

Tags: jquery

I have this situation:

Two columns with information one with *questions* and one with *answers*. I want to click in one question and show in the next column the answer. The question can have multiple answers so I need to show multiple elements with a single click.

I wrote some code taking a value with some `data attribute` like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="evidence">
    <div data-answer=".A,.B">1</div>
    <div data-answer=".B,.C">2</div>
    <div data-answer=".A,.C">3</div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <div class="A">A</div>
    <div class="B">B</div>
    <div class="C">C</div>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.evidence').on('click','div',function(){
        $('.answer div').hide();
        var ans = $(this).data('answer');
        $(ans).show();
    })
})
```

Here is the [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9hL881L/).

It works but my question is if there is some way to improve my code avoiding write each classname in the answer column maybe showing the elements with `eq()` or some more efficient way.

Thanks

Comment: You would still have to somehow tell Javascript which questions correspond to which answers... I can't see a much more efficient way than the way you've used. Other possibilities are to 'tag' the *answers* using class names (e.g. answer A can have tags `this-answers-q1` and `this-answers-q3`), or to dynamically generate the entire HTML based on a JS object/array of questions/answers?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Shai I was wonder in the case I have too many answers I want to avoid the class names also the answers can correspond to multiple questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is another way to store the answers. You store all the indexes (yeah I know, not really index since it starts with 1 but I couldn't find a better word) of the answers in an array and assign them to the index of the evidence.

```js
var answers = {
    1: [1, 2, 3],
    2: [2, 3],
    3: [1, 3]
};

$('.evidence').on('click', 'div', function () {
    var ans = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('.answer div').hide().filter(function () {
        return answers[ans].indexOf($(this).index() + 1) > -1;
    }).show();
});
```

```css
.evidence {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
.answer {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
}
.evidence div, .answer div {
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    text-align:Center;
}
.answer div {
    background:orange;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="evidence">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle to play with the code http://jsfiddle.net/g9hL881L/1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer it seems a pretty nice aproach

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer who loves non intrusive coding, i would rather save the data in JSON and build a function to find associations based on the data retreived from the evidence divs:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {"questions":[
        {"evidence":"1", "answers" : ["A", "B"]},
        {"evidence":"2", "answers" : ["B", "C"]},
        {"evidence":"3", "answers" : ["A", "C"]}
    ]};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".evidence div a").click(function(){
        var evidence = $(this).text();
        $.each(data.questions, function(key, value){
            if(value.evidence == evidence)
            {
                $.each(value.answers, function(key2, answer){
                    alert(answer);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="evidence">
        <div><a href="#">1</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">2</a></div>
        <div><a href="#">3</a></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the purpose of the demo, I display the result in an alert but you could change that

Using JSON is the best way to store data in javascript (AngularJS is a good exemple of JSON driven apps). If you want to extend your application, you will be able store the data in a database and have a backend send if to you.

Isn't that fantastic!

http://jsfiddle.net/o6xtcsx8/

Comment: Thanks for the answer ... I don't see the demo

Comment: Thanks again it seems to work but I don't see how to apply this to my particular case also .. I don't know about JSON you go with +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to accomplish that

- Get the `div`s length of the `.answer`
- Get the index of the `clicked div`
- Get the `next div` index ( would be the `clicked div` + 1 )

  - Reset the `next div` index if the `clicked div` is the last one

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g9hL881L/4/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.evidence').on('click','div',function(){
        $('.answer div').hide();
        $divLen = $('.answer div').length;
        $thsIndx = $(this).index();
        // reset the index if the clicked is the last div
        $nextIndex = ( ($thsIndx + 1) === $divLen ) ? 0 : ($thsIndx + 1);
        $('.answer div').eq($thsIndx).show();
        $('.answer div').eq($nextIndex).show();
    });
});
```

```css
.evidence {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}
.answer {
    width:200px;
    float:right;
}
.evidence div, .answer div {
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px;
    margin-bottom:15px;
    background:red;
    color:white;
    text-align:Center;
}
.answer div {
    background:orange;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="evidence">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
    <div>A</div>
    <div>B</div>
    <div>C</div>
</div>
```