# Link logic with slide and hide/show?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to hide/show some content in the same div by pressing external links like this one:

jsfiddle.net/g9hL881L/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.evidence').on('click','div',function(){
    $('.answer div').hide();
    var ans = $(this).data('answer');
    $(ans).show();
})
})

$('.close').click(function() {
$(".answer").hide();
});
```

I have add a close link to the "A" div, but if I press the close link, the divs get hide and I cant show them again by the links 1,2,3 - where I have to integrate the "toggle"?

[FIDDL](http://jsfiddle.net/3c7uu0tv/)

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of this whole website

Comment: Snatch, your phrasing is a bit confusing. Can you reframe the question to be a bit more concise?

Comment: Check the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/q/25936146/2887133

Comment: Thx Danko (and Growler) for helping me! The link from Danko is what I am looking for!! Big thx!! By the way, how can I modify this code, that the A, B, C div get closed, if I click on it?

Comment: You have to add `x: []` to the answers variable where x is the index of the div +1 that acts as a close link.... although I would suggest the most basic approach http://jsfiddle.net/7n2d4b44/2/. Also in your new code you need to use `$(".answer div").hide()` in the close click

Comment: Thx Spokey!! Perfect work - thats absolutly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle out for an example.

http://jsfiddle.net/SkiWether/KFmLv/

To simplify their solution, I'll share the high level concept:

1) Add an event handler to the element you want to click on to make the animation happen...

```
 $('a').click()
```

2) Add another event handler within `$("a").click(` that runs `toggle` whenever your link is clicked. In this case I'm selecting all `p` elements

```
 $('p').toggle()
```

3) Add parameters to the toggle animation, such as `"slide", "left", 500 milliseconds`

```
 $('p').toggle("slide", "left", 500);
```

Altogether:

```
 $("a").click(function () {    
     $('p').toggle("slide", "left", 500);
 });
```

Then it's a matter of adding in logic to check which elements are shown at what time.

Comment: @Snatch if this answers your question, please accept the answer